# How to allow only 11 numbers in input filed

Tags: jquery

I have an input field and i want to allow only 11 numbers user can input, and after 11 numbers he can enter only dash (-) and then second 11 number digit. I am beginner please help me. How can i achieve this?
After dash - and number is optional. I am using jquery and am trying but didnt get anything. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

```js
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="e.g 03xxxxxxxxx-03xxxxxxxxx" id="contact" oninput="update()">
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [inputmask](https://robinherbots.github.io/Inputmask/index.html) to create the desired result.

```
$('#contact').inputmask("99999999999-[99999999999]", {
  "placeholder": "03xxxxxxxxx-03xxxxxxxxx",
  onincomplete: function() {
    $(this).val('');
  }
});
```

This will generate both a placeholder and a "set" the maximum characters allowed based on your pattern.

**Demo**

```js
$('#contact').inputmask("99999999999-[99999999999]", {
  "placeholder": "03xxxxxxxxx-03xxxxxxxxx",
  onincomplete: function() {
    $(this).val('');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact"  >
```

Comment: actually, the problem is that dash and after dash number is optional. So how can I achieve that? by using mask, because if you use mask you have write complete

Comment: @Iqrakhan Problem is that "After dash, number is optional" is not a requirement of your original question. Please make sure you have given us all information before you post the question.

Comment: inputmask("99999999999-99999999999"  here after dash number is optional

Comment: @Iqrakhan I gave you the tools for this. Did you try search for inputmast optional characters? If i do, i find the answer in 1 min. `99999999999-[99999999999]`